# Get connected devices in wireless network

Tags: java, android

**Hello,
I search how detect the devices connected in my wireless network.**

```
 public class WiFiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WifiDirect activity;
    private PeerListListener myPeerListListener;
    public WiFiBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, WifiDirect activity){
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
               Toast.makeText(context, " Wifi P2P is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(context, " Wi-Fi P2P is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Lis of devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, myPeerListListener);
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        }
    }
}
```

But this code showed a toast contained the message : Wifi P2P is enabled
what is the problem.
Please help me.

Comment: Look at this sample. It may help you : https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery

Comment: I saw this link but I have not understand how to use it.

Comment: Download the example and run it.

Comment: Yes it execute but how I used this program in my application